# Display input error message within the page

Tags: php, javascript, forms, browser

[image: This is what I want]

I'm very new to PHP.  I'm not trying to validate username or password, but instead I just want to make sure the user will input valid characters for their names.  And, instead of redirecting them to a blank page with just the error message I want to display the error message like it is in the picture above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that Ajax would be the fit solution for your problem. I suggest you take a look at [jQuery.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/), and google for some "**form validation using jquery**" for tutorials.

Comment: I've never used JQuery in my life, but after finding [this](http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/tutorials/building-real-time-form-validation-using-jquery/). It's worth learning it because that's exactly what I want.

Answer (score 1):

This is done live with javascript. In the case of basic character validity a static js function would do.  If you want to do something like check availability of a username on sign up you would need to use ajaxs to check with the server.